# "bad value for range" is raised in rspec/turnip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm using turnip for testing.

I wrote the following test:

```rb
session = ActionDispatch::Integration::Session.new(Rails.application)
str = "Basic " + Base64.strict_encode64("#{@token}:#{@secret}")
session.get "/api/v1/recommend/#{n}", nil, {"Authorization" => str}
```

I used ActionDispatch::Integration::Session.new(Rails.application) because turnip don't support `get`.

@token and @secret are values for token and token_secret, and I confirmed these values are valid.
n is given at arguments.

Next, I run it and these errors occurred:

```
Failures:

  1) test
     Failure/Error: test1
     ArgumentError:
       bad value for range
     # ./spec/features/recommendation.feature:13:in `test1'
     # ./app/models/user.rb:682:in `recommendation'
     # ./app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb:209:in `recommendation'
     # spec/steps/recommendation_steps.rb:32:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/features/recommendation.feature:14:in `block (6 levels) in run'
     # ./spec/features/recommendation.feature:13:in `each'
     # ./spec/features/recommendation.feature:13:in `block (5 levels) in run'
     # -e:1:in `<main>'
```

I tried the following cases and confirmed they are successful.

1. Do same things in rails console
2. Make a dummy encoded string and use it (of course authentication was failing, but no error)

Why did such errors occur?

(Added)

`./app/models/user.rb:682:in recommendation`:

```rb
  def recommendation limit = 10
    result = Hash.new{0.0}
    unused_recipe_ids = Recipe.where.not(id: self.made_recipes.pluck(:id)).pluck(:id)
    self.made_activities.includes(:recipe).each do |activity|
      c = coefficient(activity)
      similarities = RecipeSimilarity.where(from_recipe_id:           activity.recipe.id).where(to_recipe_id: unused_recipe_ids)
      similarities.each { |s| result[s.to_recipe_id] += s.score * c }
    end
    Recipe.where(id: result.sort{|a, b| b[1] <=> a[1]}[0...limit].map{|r| r[0]})
  end

  def coefficient activity
    return 1.5 if activity.type_code == 301
    return 0.5 if activity.type_code == 302
    if activity.type_code == 100
      return 1.0 if activity.evaluation == 0
      return 0.1 if activity.evaluation == 1
      return 0.6 if activity.evaluation == 2
      return 1.1 if activity.evaluation == 3
      return 1.6 if activity.evaluation == 4
      return 2.5 if activity.evaluation == 5
    end
    return 1.0
  end
```

`./app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb:209:in recommendation`:

```rb
  def recommendation
    @recipes = @current_user.recommendation(params[:limit])
    render text: @recipes.to_json
  end
```

Recipe.count is 50.
RecipeSimilarity.count is 2500.

Comment: We don't know what your code does.  What is happening at `./app/models/user.rb:682` or `./app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb:209`?

Comment: In `.app/models/user.rb:682`, `Recipe.where(id: result.sort{|a, b| b[1] <=> a[1]}[0...limit].map{|r| r[0]})`

Comment: In `./app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb:209`, `@recipes = @current_user.recommendation(params[:limit])`

Comment: Oh, I have believed the error was occurred at authenticate, but it's not true...?

Comment: glad you solved it could it have something to do with the fact that `limit` is not set to `10` by default because even if you pass `nil` it overwrites the default ;).